# A time travel novel featuring 2 kids, starts in a railway station

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

I read this in my English textbook about 10 years back, just a small part of a novel, as it was mentioned there.

It starts off with 2 kids (a boy and his sister, probably twins) getting off at a railway station and finding out the station and the environment seems rather old-fashioned. As they take a walk to the exit of it, they get really confused as to where they've come. Actually their uncle had to pick them up but they don't find him anywhere.

As they reach the exit some guy hands them over a pendant (maybe they buy it) which has a note in it, written by their uncle, who seems to give them a clue on his whereabouts and informs them of some strange happening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a novel, but this sounds weirdly like a puzzle book called *Time Train to Ancient Rome*, published 1988 (and reprinted quite a while later).  Probably not the one you're looking for, but I thought I'd mention it.

https://archive.org/details/timetraintoancie00gaby

Story is about Bill and his sister Lucy who go to see their uncle Sidney, but when they get off the train they're in Ancient Rome and he's not there.  A boy hands them a coded message on a wax tablet, which the reader has to decipher, some Roman money and two golden pendants which turn out to have the power to translate Latin for them.  Following the instructions on the wax tablet they track down Uncle Sidney, who does indeed seem to know what's going on, and from there the three of them have to foil a plot to kill the Emperor.

Comment: Well, fancy it being that!  What was it doing in an English textbook, or was it not there you saw it after all?  I used to love those Usborne puzzle books - I think I've still got *Time Train* somewhere.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds a lot like the beginning of Andre Norton's *Red Hart Magic*. Two children, a boy and a girl, the same age but not twins, step siblings, are shipped off to stay with their aunt, they aren't met at the train station as arranged. The boy buys a model of an old road house, the old Red Hart Inn, I think the girl buys a necklace I'm not sure, and I can't quite remember how the uncle who was collecting them gets word to them. As I recall their uncle seems to know more about the inn and the strangeness that comes with it than you'd expect. The time travel in *Red Hart Magic* comes later once they settle in at their aunt's, the children end up travelling back into the history of the inn and taking a number of historical roles from its colourful past.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Moltres No worries, I'm happy to help, and that I got it right, I wasn't completely sure about this one.

Comment: Hey, I just saw the date published of the novel. It's 2014. However, I'd read the excerpt I mentioned back in 2009 or so.

Comment: *Red Hard Magic* published 1976.